# Correct way to access a function in a scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using user contributed modules that I am trying not to edit so that upgrades are nice and easy.

I'm attempting to allow a user to browse to a CSV File on the local filesystem, parse it and display it in a dynamic table.  To do this I'm utilizing `PapaParse`, `ui.grid` and `angularFileUpload`.

The problem I'm running into is that they all work at different levels at the hierarchy.

angularFileUpload is nice an easy - it calls a function in my controller (using controllerAs syntax). That function then runs a PapaParse function to convert the CSV file to a JSON Object (all working so far).

The problem I have is that `ui.grid` works on the $scope object since it's a attribute directive and doesn't support watchers to monitor for changes to a variable (you have to call a function on data update to re-bind the data).

So the question is, from within my controller whats the **correct/recommended** way to communicate with an external directive without editing the directive to listen to messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ui.grid` should bind to changes of its associated data. Therefore you should only change your local $scope, to which the grid is also bound, and everything works fine.

As you mentioned, directives do not listen to messages, but that's is also not how Angular works. Angular forces data-binding, so by binding a field into the directive, the component should take care of updating its presentation, as soon as you change the model you bound it to.

Unfortunately, `ui.grid` does not adhere to this convention. Therefore you have to render the grid as soon as you user's data is there (inside the function that is called after opening the file or via `$watch`). This can for example be done via `ngIf`, where the child directive is only loaded when a field is true. When the user switches between two CSVs, you could set the value to false, load the data in your model and set it to true again. Be sure that there is one digest cycle (e.g. via `$timeout`) in between so that your change affects the UI.

Comment: It doesn't appear to listen to changes :\ http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/316_dynamic_data_changes

Comment: That's bad. Perhaps conditional rendering can help you. Basically if you chose another CSV you always have to rerender the complete thing, so its not against the mindset of `ui.grid` if you do so.

Comment: Well the problem i'm having is how to communicate with the scope of a element from a controller..

Comment: A controller should in general only work on his own scope. If the element does not bind to anything from the controller he is not responsible for doing anything with the control.